# Rounding results in OLS regression

Tags: output, rounding, stata

This is my regression and its output:

[image: OUTPUT STATA]

How can I round the coefficients and the standard errors in two decimal places?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the option `cformat()`.

For example::

```
sysuse auto

regress price length, cformat(%5.2f)

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        74
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 72)        =     16.50
       Model |   118425867         1   118425867   Prob > F        =    0.0001
    Residual |   516639529        72  7175549.01   R-squared       =    0.1865
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.1752
       Total |   635065396        73  8699525.97   Root MSE        =    2678.7

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      length |      57.20      14.08     4.06   0.000        29.13       85.27
       _cons |   -4584.90    2664.44    -1.72   0.090     -9896.36      726.56
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the Stata [manual](https://www.stata.com/manuals/rregress.pdf#rregressOptionsdisplay_options) for `regress` there is a useful discussion of display options.